# Formatar texto Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um sistema e preciso justificar o texto a esquerda, já tentei com o textbox e com ritchtext e nenhum dos dois me dar essa opção, apenas consigo alinha a esquerda, porém quando eu alinho só a primeira coluna de texto fica alinhada, as outras seguem o alinhamento e bagunçam, o ideal seria eu justificar a esquerda pois as colunas ficariam todas alinhadas.[image: Coluna bagunçada]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, na propriedade `TextAlign` do `TextBox` você coloque como `left`.

Na hora de preencher o `TextBox` já deixe a sua `string` formatada, ex:

```
public static void Main()
{
  string[] names = { "Adam", "Bridgette", "Carla", "Daniel", "Ebenezer","Francine", "George" };
  decimal[] hours = { 40, 6.667m, 40.39m, 82, 40.333m, 80, 16.75m };

  Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,5}\n", "Name", "Hours");

  for (int ctr = 0; ctr < names.Length; ctr++)
     Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,5:N1}", names[ctr], hours[ctr]);

}
```

Resultado:

```
// The example displays the following output:
//       Name                 Hours
//
//       Adam                  40.0
//       Bridgette              6.7
//       Carla                 40.4
//       Daniel                82.0
//       Ebenezer              40.3
//       Francine              80.0
//       George                16.8
```

Fonte: [Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)

Comment: O problema é que eu não estou digitando, esse texto vêm de um documento que eu pego e converto, o programa serve pra adicionar alguns campos e parâmetros ao documento.

Comment: Entendo, mas este código é só um exemplo. Quando você ler o documento faça a formatação nele antes de jogar para o TextBox.